# Nesting and ordering by largest to smallest amounts for multiple nest levels in XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, grouping

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Amounts](
    [EmpID] [int] NULL,
    [Amount] [smallmoney] NULL
) 

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees](
    [LastName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LocationID] [int] NULL,
    [EmpID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) 

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Locations](
    [LocationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [City] [varchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Amounts] ([EmpID], [Amount]) VALUES (7, 4750.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Amounts] ([EmpID], [Amount]) VALUES (2, 15750.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Amounts] ([EmpID], [Amount]) VALUES (7, 18100.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Amounts] ([EmpID], [Amount]) VALUES (4, 21000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Amounts] ([EmpID], [Amount]) VALUES (3, 18100.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Amounts] ([EmpID], [Amount]) VALUES (10, 41000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Amounts] ([EmpID], [Amount]) VALUES (7, 25000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Amounts] ([EmpID], [Amount]) VALUES (11, 21500.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Amounts] ([EmpID], [Amount]) VALUES (5, 9900.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Amounts] ([EmpID], [Amount]) VALUES (7, 95900.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Amounts] ([EmpID], [Amount]) VALUES (9, 55000.0000)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Andrews', N'Alex', 1, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Brown', N'Barry', 1, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Jones', N'Lee', 2, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Kendal', N'David', 1, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Birch', N'Eric', 1, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Kircher', N'Lisa', 4, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Williams', N'David', 1, 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Marshall', N'John', NULL, 8)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Howard', N'James', 2, 9)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'O''Donnell', N'Terry', 2, 10)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Smythe', N'Sally', 1, 11)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Donovan', N'Barbara', 4, 12)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employees] ([LastName], [FirstName], [LocationID], [EmpID]) VALUES (N'Wagner', N'Phil', 1, 13)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Employees] OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Locations] ([LocationID], [City]) VALUES (1, N'Paris')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Locations] ([LocationID], [City]) VALUES (2, N'Sydney')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Locations] ([LocationID], [City]) VALUES (3, N'Chicago')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Locations] ([LocationID], [City]) VALUES (4, N'London')
GO
```

I want to generate XML which is ordered by the city which contains the highest overall amount first and then, nested within that, each employee (ordered by those with the highest total amount first) and then nested within each employee their amounts (highest first).

The following query (rather complex - please let me know if there is a simpler/cheaper way) gives the right ordering but I am stuck on how to get the XML(Elements) nesting as I have described.

```
;
WITH cte  as
(
SELECT City, 
       FirstName,
       LastName,
       Amount, 
       SUM(Amount)OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(LastName, FirstName) ORDER BY CONCAT(LastName, FirstName) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Total
FROM Locations l
INNER JOIN Employees e
ON l.LocationID = e.LocationID 
INNER JOIN Amounts a
ON a.EmpID = e.EmpID
GROUP BY City, LastName, FirstName, Amount
)
SELECT City, FirstName,LastName,Amount
FROM cte
ORDER BY SUM(Total)OVER(PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Total DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) DESC, Total DESC, Amount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler looking query giving the same results:

```
SELECT City, 
       FirstName,
       LastName,
       Amount
FROM Locations l
INNER JOIN Employees e
ON l.LocationID = e.LocationID 
INNER JOIN Amounts a
ON a.EmpID = e.EmpID
GROUP BY City, LastName, FirstName, Amount
order by city,SUM(Amount)OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(LastName, FirstName) ORDER BY CONCAT(LastName, FirstName) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) desc,Amount desc,  firstname, lastname
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3f9d/12)